# How to bindBidirectional comboboxes and checkboxes

Tags: binding, javafx, javafx-8

I've the following class:

```
    public class Model {
    ...
    private SimpleStringProperty currency;
    public SimpleStringProperty currencyProperty() {
            if(currency == null){
                currency = new SimpleStringProperty();
            }
            return currency;
        }
    ...
    }
```

And I bind (textfield) to above class as follows:

```
@FXMLController("view.fxml")
public class Controller {
...
@FXML
    private TextField tf_acc_num;
@Inject
    private Model model;
...
@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
tf_acc_num.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.currencyProperty());
...
}}
```

It is Ok. What about binding comboboxes and checkboxes? Assume Combobox as

```
@FXML
    private ComboBox<String> cb_currency;
```

and I put values in it inside `init()` method

```
cb_currency.getItems().addAll(
                "USD", "EUR", "RUB"
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does

```
cb_currency.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.currencyProperty());
```

work?

Comment: It worked.)) Thanks. What about Checkboxes? could you please help)) and Date))

Comment: For a checkbox you would bind a `BooleanProperty` in the model to the `selectedProperty` of the checkbox. For a `DatePicker` bind the `valueProperty` to an `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>` in the model....